# Where is undo function?

Tags: meshlab

I am trying Meshlab, but immediately hit an issue with the apparent lack of an 'Undo" command after trying a cleanup transformation that had undesired results.

As a (less than ideal) workaround I tried the 'reload' function, which simply displayed the object again in its transformed state, even though at no time had I saved the object in that state.

If I restart Meshlab then load the object again, only then does it show in its original state.  Not sure if this is a single issue or two issues (one of which being a bug) - but either way, how can I achieve effective 'Undo' functionality? that would allow me to try a transformation without having to quit and restart Meshlab after every unsuccessful result?

Comment: As of today [Nov 2023], there is still no progress in the 'Undo' button development. [issue](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/376)

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately there is no Undo feature in MeshLab (a longstanding gripe).

The Reload button should reload the mesh from the source file (although I have found that it doesn't reload textures). If this is not working for you then it sounds like a bug that you should report.

The only other workaround I can recommend is to duplicate your mesh before running any potentially destructive filters; if the results are undesirable you can delete the duplicate and try again.